# How can I understand the following commands in /etc/default/automysqlbackup?

Tags: ubuntu, shell

I'm trying to understand the following commands in `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` file:

```
USERNAME=`grep user /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | tail -n 1 | cut -d"=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`

PASSWORD=`grep password /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | tail -n 1 | cut -d"=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`

DBNAMES=`find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d'/' -f5 | grep -v ^mysql\$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `

DBNAMES=`mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --execute="SHOW DATABASES" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v ^Database$ | grep -v ^mysql$ | grep -v ^performance_schema$ | grep -v ^information_schema$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

but I don't get it at all.
I would really appreciate if somebody could explain to me what's going on in there step-by-step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
USERNAME=`grep user /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | tail -n 1 | cut -d"=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

runs a pipeline with the following commands:

- `grep user /etc/mysql/debian.cnf`, which extracts all lines containing “user” from `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`;
- `tail -n 1`, which shows only the last line of its input;
- `cut -d"=" -f2`, which extracts the second part of the line delimited by “=”;
- `awk '{print $1}'`, which removes all the spaces surrounding the first word in the line.

The purpose (not perfectly implemented) of all this is to extract the last value assigned to `user` in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. The result is stored in a variable named `USERNAME`.

The `PASSWORD` line is similar.

```
DBNAMES=`find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d'/' -f5 | grep -v ^mysql\$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

runs the following commands:

- `find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`, which lists the directories in `/var/lib/mysql`, with their full paths;
- `cut -d'/' -f5`, which extracts the fifth field delimited by “/”, *i.e.* the directories’ names;
- `grep -v ^mysql\$`, which removes any line matching exactly “mysql”;
- `tr \\\r\\\n ,\` , which replaces all carriage returns with “,” and all newlines with a space.

The purpose is to list all the directories in `/var/lib/mysql`, separated by spaces, excluding the `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` directory. The result is stored in a variable named `DBNAMES`.

```
DBNAMES=`mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --execute="SHOW DATABASES" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v ^Database$ | grep -v ^mysql$ | grep -v ^performance_schema$ | grep -v ^information_schema$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

has the same purpose, but it parses the output of MySQL’s `SHOW DATABASES` command. `awk '{print $1}'` is used to extract the first word from each line, then all the `grep`s filter out various values.